# tweepy importing error while calling through AJAX

Tags: python, ajax, tweepy, internal-server-error

I am trying to **retrieve tweets** of **searched user**. It throws **Internal Server Error - 500** when I add **"import tweepy"** in python script. If I **comment** **"import tweepy"** then it runs normally. But I need **"import tweepy"** to run **twitter API**.

***Code (AJAX) script:***

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../views/ajax/search_tweets.py",
    type: "post",
    data: {"query" : "@user_name"},
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
})
```

***Python script:***

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import cgi
import json
import traceback
import tweepy         # when I import this, it throws 500 error

class SearchTweets(object):

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.debug = 1
            o_auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('*******', '*******')
            o_auth .set_access_token('*******', '*******')
            self.twitter_api = tweepy.API( o_auth, parser=tweepy.parsers.JSONParser()  )
        except Exception:
            import traceback
            print traceback.format_exc()

    def searchTweetsVia(self, query):
        try:
            tweets = {}
            tweets = self.twitter_api.search( query, result_type='popular' )
            return ""
        except Exception:
            import traceback
            print traceback.format_exc()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        fs = cgi.FieldStorage()
        print "\n"
        query = fs.getvalue("query")
        SearchTweets().searchTweetsVia(query)
        print json.dumps(query)
    except Exception:
        import traceback
        print traceback.format_exc()
```

How to fix this error. I need **tweepy** library.

Comment: This may be a typo from bringing code over to SO but in your `searchTweetsVia` method, you return `""`. Is that `tweets` in your actual code?

Comment: @AustinA : I have only return "". It doesn't affect on code. Ignore it. Actual problem is 'import tweepy'

Comment: Next question is how does the python script run when you execute it without using AJAX? I'm assuming you've done this and it worked fine but I thought I would still ask.

Comment: @AustinA : It runs without AJAX successfully. I don't know why "import tweepy" throws error "internal server error" while running through AJAX. Problem is when I use AJAX.

Comment: How are you running AJAX? It sounds like you might have a webapp deployed on a server or are you just running this locally?

Comment: @AustinA: I am running this locally.

Comment: How many versions of python do you have on your machine and how did you install tweepy? Did you use pip?

Comment: I have 2 version python 2.7 and 3. Default is python 2.7 and I used pip to install tweepy.

Comment: Go to `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` and make sure tweepy is in there. AJAX should be calling your default python version but since it's only throwing an error with tweepy, I believe that there's an issue with the way tweepy is installed in that version of python.